# I have a pool pump on a 30 amp circuit. Can I add a 20 amp GFCI outlet to that same 30 amp breaker. Pump is on 12 gauge wire

Tags: wiring

I want to put a 20 amp GFCI receptacle on a 30 amp breaker.

Is this ok?

The 30 amp breaker is for a pool pump on 115v.

Comment: It looks like you are already out of spec on the circuit wires to the pump. 30 amp circuits need 10 AWG wire

Comment: I think they were indicating the wiring on the pump itself, and not the circuit feeding the pump. Not unlike an appliance wire being a lower gauge than what's feeding the receptacle. But even if that's the case, we need a lot more detail. How many amps does the pump require? How will the outlet be used?

Comment: The tap rule for cooking appliances 210.19.a.3 is very specific to household ranges and cooking appliances. This would NOT meet code.

Comment: I took to long to edit after hitting enter by mistake.  If a small panel like a hot tub GFCI with additional breakers it could be done this way. where the main GFCI feeds the pump and a gfci breaker or outlet is fed from one of the additional slots in the panel. Something like this [panel](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Midwest-Electric-Products-50-Amp-240-Volt-240-Watt-Non-Fuse-Metallic-Spa-Panel-Disconnect-with-GFI-UG412RMW250P/100686230) the wire size would need to be increased if it is 10 awg or GFCI reduced.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a 30 amp circuit.  Your wire is 12 gauge, so you have a 20 amp circuit with the wrong breaker.

- Replace the breaker with 20A
- Feel free to install your 15 or 20 amp GFCI since they are legal on 20A circuits
- For that matter, you could just install a GFCI breaker. Price both ways.

Gadgets which run on 120V/30A are almost nonexistent.  Nobody builds devices that way.  If it needs that much power, they kick up to 240V/15A, which permits use of 14 gauge wire instead of 10 gauge.

If this pump really is 120V/30A, you are going to have to run new 10 gauge wire anyway.  Generally things that large are given their own circuit.   Might as well re-task the 20A circuit to the outlets.

Comment: I could be wrong (might be a local ammendment), but I don't think you're allowed to have a general use receptacle on the pump circuit.

Comment: The 2011 code mentions cord-and-plug connected pool pumps several times (680.21b, 680.31) but those do not mention dedicated circuits. Makes sense, a small pump like 4A shouldn't need a whole circuit... there might be other rules that compel it with a larger pump.  It calls out many cases where GFCI is required, I'd just put one in rather than "lawyer" all that.

Comment: I don't think the circuit has to be dedicated only to a pump, but I don't think you can have general use receptacles on the circuit.  I thought there's something about only single receptacles, meaning no duplex receptacles. But again, I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I remember seeing that.  Don't have my code in front of me but IIRC it's an exception to the 10-foot rule that allows outlets in the 6-10 foot zone if they are single and for the pump and several other conditions.  It wasn't clear to me whether single outlet meant at that location or in the entire circuit.  Figuring the Code has to cover any conceivable arrangement of pool, I could see localities who see a pattern of arrangements might refine further.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot install a 20 ampere receptacle on a 30 ampere circuit. Section 210.21(B)(3) of the National Electrical Code, says that a receptacle on a 30 ampere branch circuit with multiple outlets must be rated for 30 amperes.  Therefore, installing a 20 ampere receptacle would be a violation.

If you think about this, it makes complete sense.  If the device plugged into the 20 ampere receptacle fails, and starts to draw more current.  The breaker will not trip, until the device draws well over 30 amperes of current. By this time, the 20 ampere device could be on fire.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 210 Branch Circuits
>
> **210.21 Outlet Devices.** Outlet devices shall have an ampere
>   rating that is not less than the load to be served and
>   shall comply with 210.21(A) and (B).
>
> **(B) Receptacles.**
>
> **(3) Receptacle Ratings.** Where connected to a branch circuit
>   supplying two or more receptacles or outlets, receptacle
>   ratings shall conform to the values listed in Table 210.21(B)(3), 
>   or, where rated higher than 50 amperes, the
>   receptacle rating shall not be less than the branch-circuit
>   rating.
>
> [image: Table 210.21(B)(3)]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tester's answer, the 12 gauge wire you have on a 30 amp breaker is a code violation.

You should change the breaker to a 20 amp breaker.

12 gauge wire is not rated for a 30 amp breaker.

Comment: For whatever reason I accidentally down voted this and am unable to take it back on the mobile SE app, sorry. I would caution the wording here. Generally speaking this is correct. However, motors are an exception and it's not unheard of to see small guage wire on what seems like a scary-sized breaker. Common misunderstanding.   In fact, a question regarding this is on the CA Gen. Electrician cert exam.

Comment: True if the pool pump is hard wired and an individual branch circuit this would be possible. Exploring this idea though, an inverse time circuit breaker would be rated at 250% reciprocating that the motor would have to draw 10 to 12 amps to warrant a 30 amp breaker and then #12 wire would actually be oversized, #14 would be fine. Additionally, a 115 volt ½ HP motor draws 9.8 amps which would require a 25 amp breaker. A ¾ HP draws 13.8 amps that would require a 35 amp breaker. I'm aware motor circuits produce strange combinations of OCPDs and wire sizes but I don't think that is the case here.

Answer (score -1):

You can. The 120 volt 30 amp is for a travel trailer, but you still need the GFCI.  You have to fuse it down; the fuse will fit in those plastic boxes. Measure carefully and use a waterproof fuse holder.